# One row database table or JSON file

Tags: design, design-patterns, database, file-systems

If I have data that I will only need to update very rarely (once a month), would it be a good idea to use a JSON file instead of a database table with only 1 row?

Comment: With a database approach you can relate that line with the others in the database. With the file you'll need to read it and initialize a CLOB to process it. Question is: the rest of the database needs to process or relate (join) in any point with that specific line?

Comment: @linuxunil good question. No, this table will never relate to any other tables, nor will it contain data to be analyzed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a database approach you can relate that line with the others in the database. With the file you'll need to read it and initialize a CLOB to process it.

#### In other words, the data will exist for the database.

Other thing to consider is that with a database comes more things that just storage of data. You get logging, transactions, permissions...

Analyze other aspects of your application to be sure that you ***really*** don't need those.

Comment: Also, if you're already using a database, then using it for the OPs record means one fewer additional component/library/etc to deal with.